# Find the nearest (small) number x where x can be represented by sum of cubes

Tags: objective-c, c, algorithm

I recently came across a problem where a number \$x\$ is given and I have to find \$y\$:

1. \$y < x > 1\$
2. \$y\$ can be expressed as \$a^3 + b^3\$ (more than one combination)

   Example:

   If 4105 is \$x\$ then 4104 is the answer, where 4104 can be expressed as \$16^3 + 2^3\$ and also \$15^3 + 9^3\$.

I am able to write a program in Objective-C, but I am sure that my method is not optimized and is not best.

I am posting this to find out

1. the best algorithms to solve this problem
2. Flaws in my way of solving

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

BOOL isPerfectCube(int cubeValue)
{
    float CalculatedCubeRoot = powf(cubeValue, 1.0/3.0);
    CalculatedCubeRoot = floorf(CalculatedCubeRoot * 100) / 100;
    return ((CalculatedCubeRoot - (int) CalculatedCubeRoot) == 0);
}

int cubeRoot(int value)
{
    return powf((float)value, 1.0/3.0);
}

int nearbyNumber(int numberUnderInvestigation)
{
    if(numberUnderInvestigation < 2)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        int firstCube = 1;
        int combination = 0;

        for(int i=2;firstCube<numberUnderInvestigation;i++)
        {
            firstCube = i*i*i;
            int nextCubeNumber = numberUnderInvestigation - firstCube;
            if(isPerfectCube(nextCubeNumber))
            {
                combination++;
            }
        }

        if(combination > 3)
        {
            return numberUnderInvestigation;
        }
        else
        {
            return nearbyNumber(numberUnderInvestigation - 1);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        int inputNumber = 4150;

        NSLog(@"%d",nearbyNumber(inputNumber));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you paste here your solution?

Comment: i am not able to format it correctly. will try it again.

Comment: You should paste the code here, and format it properly. If you have issues with that, google or ask around. If the problem is that there is too much code to be formatted, maybe you should paste only relevant part of it? Without the code (or with poorly formatted code) it's pretty hard to help you out. Sometimes some good soul will correct your invalid formatting, but you should not count on it.

Comment: edited and added the code to the post. I wrote the program in Objective-C

Comment: I guess x and y, or result cannot be less than zero. If I am not wrong you should write another condition to question.

Comment: Did you try to get a list of increasing cubes and a list of decreasing cubes, start at the beginning of both, compute the sum, and advance in one if the sum is smaller than x, in the other if the sum in greater than x?

Comment: I guess you have to work something else to meet your 'several combinations' criterion.

Comment: y < x > 1... well that gives you all the room in the world... `1^3 + 1^3 + 1^3...` all integers are the sum of 1^3 (or -1^3)... do you mean `1 < y < x` ?

Comment: @GradyPlayer, one of the original conditions was `y = a^3 + b^3`, so the situation what you have outlined is not a solution for this problem, therefore the original condition about `y < x > 1` is correct, even if it looks odd.

Answer (score 4):

personally I would calculate that value like e.g. this:

```
/* 
 * check the updated algorithm, please
 *
- (Float64)neareastSmallerSumOfCubes:(NSInteger)originalNumber {
    if (originalNumber > 1) {
        Float64 _firstAttempt = pow((Float64)originalNumber, 1.0/3.0);
        if (_firstAttempt == floor(_firstAttempt)) originalNumber--;
        NSInteger _a = pow((Float64)originalNumber, 1.0/3.0);
        NSInteger _b = pow((Float64)originalNumber - pow(_a, 3.0), 1.0/3.0);
        return pow(_a, 3.0) + pow(_b, 3.0);
    } else {
        return MAXFLOAT;
    }
}
*/
```

## update

1. thank for *@Szu*, he has highlighted an issue with some large numbers;
2. thank for *@Rob*, he has highlighted an issue when input is already a pure sum of cubed;

I've updated the algorithm a bit according to the feedbacks, here is the final solution:

```
- (Float64) neareastSmallerSumOfCubes:(NSInteger)originalNumber {
    if (originalNumber > 1) {
        Float64 _firstAttempt = pow((Float64)originalNumber, 1.0/3.0);
        if (_firstAttempt == floor(_firstAttempt)) originalNumber--;
        NSInteger _a = pow((Float64)originalNumber, 1.0/3.0);
        NSInteger _b = pow((Float64)originalNumber - pow(_a, 3.0), 1.0/3.0);
        if (_b > 1) _b--;
        NSInteger _s = round(pow((Float64)originalNumber / 2.0, 1.0/3.0));
        Float64 _neareast = 0.0;
        do {
            Float64 _possibleNearest = pow(_a, 3.0) + pow(_b, 3.0);
            if (_possibleNearest > originalNumber) _a--;
            else if (_possibleNearest > _neareast && _possibleNearest != originalNumber) _neareast = _possibleNearest, _b++;
            else _b++;
        } while (_b <= _s);
        return _neareast;
    } else {
        return MAXFLOAT;
    }
}
```

#### random test values:

- 99998 returns 99937 (= 33<sup>3</sup> + 40<sup>3</sup>) *(runtime O(36))*
- 4105 returns 4104 (= 16<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup>) *(runtime O(17))*
- 1023 returns 1008 (= 10<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup>) *(runtime O(11))*
- 999 returns 945 (= 9<sup>3</sup> + 6<sup>3</sup>) *(runtime O(6))*
- 216 returns 189 (= 5<sup>3</sup> + 4<sup>3</sup>) *(runtime O(4))*
- 3 returns 2 (= 1<sup>3</sup> + 1<sup>3</sup>) *(runtime O(1))*

---

#### explanation

let us get the two essential conditions from the OP

1. *y < x > 1*;
2. *y* can be expressed with *a<sup>3</sup> + b<sup>3</sup>*;
3. where *x, y ∈ ℕ*, *a, b ∈ ℕ+* and *a > 0, b > 0* (that last condition obviously has to be satisfied);

---

#### #1

we know *1<sup>3</sup> + 1<sup>3</sup> < x < (x+1)<sup>1/3</sup> + (x+1)<sup>1/3</sup>*, therefore the actual smaller value also *must be* in this interval.

if we can build a simple *(x+1)<sup>1/3</sup>* by *(x+1)<sup>1/3</sup>* matrix which holds every possible combination of sums of cubes, that matrix *must* contain the value we are chasing.

> COMMENT: after certain number of iterations (maximum number of iterations: *((x+1)<sup>1/3</sup>)<sup>2</sup>)* the requested nearest smaller value can be extracted from that massive interval via e.g. brutal-force algorithms, but we are looking for a much efficient solution than that.

#### #2

we know the already the addition is commutative operand, so `a+b=b+a`, so we can drop the part under the diagonal of the matrix, so we can stop the iteration later when we reach the column *s = (x/2)<sup>1/3</sup>*. the *s* is rounded down to the nearest natural, *s ∈ ℕ*.

#### #3

the possible values are at certain locations in the half matrix, the possible elements are on an *exponential curve*, that helps to establish the actual logic of the iterations.

we need to find where this curve enters the matrix, and we walk through the values of the matrix what the curve intersects.

the enter row index is the *whole* part of *a = x<sup>1/3</sup>* and the column index is the *whole* part of the *b = (x - a<sup>3</sup>)<sup>1/3</sup>*.

we know:

1. *a > s > b* is always true, therefore:
2. *x > a<sup>3</sup> + b<sup>3</sup>*; that value also can be the possible nearest smaller, which we called *y*.
3. *x < (a+1)<sup>3</sup> + (b+1)<sup>3</sup>*;
4. we don't know the relation between *x* and *a<sup>3</sup> + (b+1)<sup>3</sup>*; that is what we will find out:

let *b = b + 1* and check what we have got:

if the *x > a<sup>3</sup> + b<sup>3</sup> > y*, that is a another possible nearest smaller; if not, we ignore it;

if the *x = a<sup>3</sup> + b<sup>3</sup>*, that is the same as input, we ignore it, according to the original *y < x* condition;

if the *x < a<sup>3</sup> + b<sup>3</sup>*, that value is greater than the original number, so we ignore it; because the *a > s > b* and *x ≧ 2s<sup>3</sup>* statements are always true, therefore *x ≧ (a-1)<sup>3</sup> + b<sup>3</sup>* will be true as well, so we can let *a = a - 1* and start the next iteration with the new *a*, *b* values.

the iteration stops when the *b* reaches the intersection of the matrix diagonal and the exponential curve, that value was calculated above as *s*; so if we reach the intersection point, we can be sure that we have already checked all possible nearest smaller values which the matrix holds; and during making the iterations we always kept the largest one as *y*, thus when we stop the algorithm, the *y* will hold the only nearest smaller value.

Comment: But there is still a condition y < x that your algorithm not meet.

Comment: @Szu, I'm feeling a bit offense in your comments... the `y < x` condition is perfectly satisfied... you just started to complain about why `216` is not `6^3` an hour ago – let me tell you the if `x = 216` the `y` must be a smaller amount (satisfying that condition), therefore the `x` cannot be `216`, because it has to be smaller. I'm sure you are highly bothered by my clever solutions, but pointless to find issues in it. :) you cannot catch it – if anyone could, I would not have posted it. :)

Comment: Hollex I am sorry. I really don't want to be rude, but I really want to explain you that your algorithm won't work well in some cases. For example number 946. Your result is 854 and mine is 945 (9^3+6^3). Another example is that number 17. Your result is 16 that is x=2^3 and y=2^3 (the fix is to add -1 in _a calculation). I must admit my first 2 complaints were wrong.

Comment: @Szu, sorry for my stupid question, but what are talking about? my algorithm presents `945` if the input was `946`, and the output is `16` if the input was `17`! I'm not sure you are testing _my_ algorithm...

Comment: And 946 wasn't a good example too.. (my implementation in C++ was faulty), but the second problem appears for big number like 99998. Your return is 99533 (46^3+13^3) when the correct value is 99937
(x=40; y=33). Please check only this case is I am wrong I won't take your time anymore.

Comment: @Szu, you mixed accidentally the `x` and `y` with `a` and `b`, because the `x=17`, `y=16`, `a=2` and `b=2`. and as you see the the condition of `y<x` is satisfied well – if I'm using the same symbols as OP.

Comment: @Szu, I've updated my algorithm, if you find something in it, please, let me know. have good fun with it! ;)

Comment: @holex can you give mathematically proof that your algorithm always gets the correct answer for all positive integers

Comment: @VikramBhat, sorry, I have deleted my recent comments – I just realised the explanation is pretty much about explaining the my background knowledge, which I have, to understand and develop such simple algorithms. it is easier to refer where the background knowledge comes from, that is pretty much covered by the _Numberical Martematics_, _Mathematical Analysis_ and _Discrete Mathematics_ subjects. no extra proof is needed, the algorithm simply _cannot_ present other value, but the requested one. I could say it was a piece of cake, but that additional background knowledge is necessary for it.

Comment: @VikramBhat While far from a proof, it can be useful to do some empirical analysis (e.g. calculate this number for all integers less than some very large number and compare holex's results to yours).

Comment: @holex There are some issues with this algorithm. First, this is returning values of `y` where `y <= x`, but the original request was `y < x` (though he may well have intended `y <= x`; it's unclear). There's a more subtle issue associated with the rounding of `pow()` when calculating `_s`. For example, if `originalNumber` is `250`, `pow((Float64)originalNumber / 2.0, 1.0/3.0)` returns something like `4.99999991`, which is truncated to `4` when stored as an integer, where clearly `5` was intended.

Comment: @Rob, **1.** rounding down the `4.99991` to `4` won't cause any problem in the calculation, however it increases the number of the iterations only. simple optimisation issue (being honest, there are also some other points where this algorithm still can be optimised, if that becomes crucial).

Comment: @Rob, **2.** the original statement (in my interpretation) was `y < x > 1`, which means means the output (`y`) should not be the same number as the input (`x`) was if the input is already a pure sum of cubes (we are looking the _nearest smaller_ value not the same one) – being greater than 1 is obvious condition, because the `1^3+0^3` is not a valid solution regarding the `0^3=0` is not considered as a cubed number.

Comment: @holex On point 2, if you test your algorithm with `4104`, it reports `4104` (i.e. 16^3 + 2^3). It should presumably report 4097 (i.e. 16^3 + 1^3).

Comment: @Rob, yep, that is a good spot, and it is quote true. I will update the algorithm soon to eliminate that.

Comment: @holex if you don't mind I made small 2 fixes to your code. Please check if fixes are correct and effective: http://pastie.org/9469145 it gives exact same result for numbers from 10 up to 10 milion.

Comment: @Szu, thank you, but I've have already made my own changes and I also add some further explanation for people how has different mathematical background from me; if you would update the shared algorithm adding the reference to this particular post, that would be much better in my view.

Comment: @holex I have a question then: if x=65 then y should be 65? Or 54?

Comment: @Szu, according to the original condition of `y < x`, the output must be less then the input, so the correct output is `54`. which interval have you checked the algorithm? :)

Comment: From 10 to 10 milion :-) Please look at pastie: http://pastie.org/9469767 I compare your results with mine. If you have any problems please ask. Btw: really nice explanation!

Comment: @VikramBhat, I've added some explanation to my answer how the algorithm works – you may consider that as proof.

Comment: @Szu, that a good result. :)

Comment: @Szu, I've found one other glitch in the algorithm, so one extra line has been added, if you like to update the external site with the latest one.

Comment: FYI, when I use your algorithm on 280, it reports 243 (6^3 + 3^3), but I believe the correct answer is 250 (5^3 + 5^3). When I use your algorithm on 945, it reports 854 (9^3 + 5^3) whereas I believe the correct answer is 855 (7^3 + 8^3).

Comment: @Rob. that is quite interesting, because `944` delivers the `855` correctly, as the `279` delivers the `250` which is also correct. :)

Comment: This latest rendition fixes 280 and 945, but introduces others. For example, 66 returns 54 = 3^3 + 3^3 rather than 65 = 1^3 + 4^3.

Comment: @Rob, I've updated the do-while cycle, now it present the correct value, including the inputs in your latest comment.

Comment: Yep, that looks much better. Only one final problem appears to linger, specifically when calculating the value for 9.

Comment: @Rob, ops, removed. :) it looked I had skipped some values which could be potential nearest smaller ones, however the theory was correct but the actual implementation of that was poor a bit...

Comment: Why are we using `Float64` rather than `double` or `CGFloat`?

Comment: Given that the original question supplies code in `main.m` and not in a class, why does your algorithm show an instance method which can only be created in a class?

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that `FLT_MAX` or `DBL_MAX` would be the preferred defines, unless you use a `CGFloat`, in which case `CGFLOAT_MAX`.

Comment: @nhgrif, I could have created a generic pseudo code instead, but the OP mentioned he is creating the algorithm in ObjC, so I felt encouraged to create a simple instance method which does the job. about `CGFloat` and `double`: the first is usually used by `CoreGraphics.framework` but the algorithm is not related to it; and I don't like to use the second one – so I used generic `Float64` which is currently an alias of `double`. the `MAXFLOAT` as return value has chosen randomly, it could have been even `-1` or even `DBL_MAX`.